# Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I am unsure why I get the error. Can anyone help please

```
L = [];
indexgood=1;
load mrsgarch_t2
eval(['L(:,',num2str(indexgood),') = Loglike(:);']);
indexgood=indexgood+1;
```

The error I get:

> Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch

thanks

Comment: What is the code trying to do?  Why do you need to use `eval`?

Comment: What is `Loglike`? Why are you using `eval`?

Comment: thanks for  replying

i tried to creat variables for each loops.

Answer (score 1):

Appernetly, the size (and dimensionality) of `L(:,indexgood)` is different than the size of `Loglike(:)`.

Is it possible that there is a saved variable `L` in the file `mrsgarch_t2.mat`?

You will get this error if the number of rows in `L` is different than the number of elements in `Loglike`.

Comment: there is a L saveed in mrsgarch. However i set L = [] already which means zero array. but when i perform another files it works. I dont understand. 

L = [];

indexgood=1;

load mrsgarch_n

eval(['L(:,',num2str(indexgood),') = Loglike(:);']);
indexgood=indexgood+1;

Comment: L is MRsGARCH_t2 is 1110x1

and loglike is 12x111

Comment: can I mitigate this problem?

Comment: are you using `L` that is saved in the mat file, or are you creating `L` anew?

Comment: thanks. I suppose to use L in the mat file and L =[] to make it easier and faster as the value wont replicate everytimes

Comment: and I get 1110x1 for L(:1) and 1333x1 for (loglike). however it is in the matfile. I cant change it. Do u know how to solve this with out change the dimension?

Answer (score 1):

From the code and other comments/answers, my guess is either that L is still empty, which could return that error when you try and access L(:,1), or that logLike(:) is not returning nice 1-d values.

Do us a favor and do: disp(L);pause before you evaluate it and see if its what you were expecting. If you could give us the class and dimensions of logLike and L once its loaded, that would be great.

Additionally, if you are loading L every time, setting L to [] is redundant and can be removed.

Comment: thanks for replying. L and loglike are in the mrsgarch_t2.mat. When I run the regression, L is 1110x1; while loglike is 11x111.

Comment: I think its because L is 1110x1, and loglike is 1333

Comment: hi Shaun314, If I set L = [] everytime I load the file. It works. Can u explain this?

Comment: but at the end, all of my loglike will become 0

Comment: I am almost positive I figured out your problem based off the comments you made yesterday, sorry for the long delay in replying. The problem is that, as you point out in the above comments, lets say A is a 2-d matrix, perhaps a 4x4 matrix. If I were to do A(:), it will return all 16 values. If I wanted to get just the first column or something of A, I would do A(:,1).

Comment: This is why your code errors, because obviously you can not assign 4 values to a matrix with only 2 values and similarly you can not assign  1333 values to 1110 values. You have two options now, turn L into a cell array so you can put a different sized vector in each cell element, or figure out what you are actually trying to accomplish with your code and make sure you are not assigning to few or to many values to one vector